# Preciso unir varios arquivos do excel em um só dividido em pastas com python. Fiz desse método mas queria criar uma função:

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Fiz essa função que recebe o diretório de destino e o mês que foi gerado os relatórios, queria fazer ela ficar menor utilizando um for que percorra essa lista:

```
ufv_name = ['CB1', 'CB2', 'CB3', 'GM1', 'IM1', 'JD2', 'PIU', 'STR'] #sigla das ufvs
```

Segue a função:

```
def unir(dir, mes):
    #IMPORTANDO OS RELATORIOS PARA UNIR EM UM SÓ
    CB1 = pd.read_excel('{}PR_CB1_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    CB2 = pd.read_excel('{}PR_CB2_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    CB3 = pd.read_excel('{}PR_CB3_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    PIU = pd.read_excel('{}PR_PIU_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    IM1 = pd.read_excel('{}PR_IM1_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    STR = pd.read_excel('{}PR_STR_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    JD2 = pd.read_excel('{}PR_JD2_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))
    GM1 = pd.read_excel('{}PR_GM1_{}.xlsx'.format(dir, mes))

    with pd.ExcelWriter('{}Relatorio_total.xlsx'.format(dir), engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        CB1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CB1', index = False)
        CB2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CB2', index = False)
        CB3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CB3', index = False)
        PIU.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='PIU', index = False)
        IM1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='IM1', index = False)
        STR.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='STR', index = False)
        JD2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='JD2', index = False)
        GM1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='GM1', index = False)

    print('Relatórios Unidos em um só arquivo')
```

Pode perceber que os relatorios importados tem sempre o mesmo padrão.

Comment: Teste esse código https://ideone.com/uPVSQv , eu fiz de cabeça pois não tenho os arquivos para testar.

Comment: Consegui fazer com seu código, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Espero que ajude você.

```
import pandas as pd

ufv_names = ['CB1','CB2','CB3']

def unir(dir, mes):
    files = [_load_file(f'{dir}PR_{name}_{mes}.xlsx') for name in ufv_names]
    names_files = list(zip(ufv_names, files))
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter('{}Relatorio_total.xlsx'.format(dir), engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        [_write_file(writer, f, name) for name, f in names_files]
        print('Relatórios Unidos em um só arquivo')

def _load_file(file):
    return pd.read_excel(file)

def _write_file(writer, file, name):
    file.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=name, index= False)
```

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui e realmente deu certo, muito obrigado! Parabéns pelo conhecimento

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível refatoração usando uma função parcial:

```
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
 
ufv_name = ['CB1', 'CB2', 'CB3', 'GM1', 'IM1', 'JD2', 'PIU', 'STR']
 
def readxlsx(ufv, d, m):
  return (pd.read_excel(f'{d}PR_{ufv}_{m}.xlsx'), ufv)
 
def unir(dir, mes):
  f = partial(readxlsx, d=dir, m=mes)
  planilhas = list(map(f, ufv_name))
  with pd.ExcelWriter(f'{dir}Relatorio_total.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for p in planilhas:
      p[0].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=p[1], index = False)
```

Uma função parcial é uma função criada a partir de outra função onde parte dos seus argumento estão previamente definidos. Em Python é disponibilizado o módulo no [functools](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html) a função [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) para criar funções parciais.

A lógica do algoritmo é simples:

- foi criada a `readxlsx(ufv, d, m)` que lê uma planilha no caminho `f'{d}PR_{ufv}_{m}.xlsx'` e a associa a `ufv` em uma tupla.
- é criada uma função parcial `f` sobre `readxlsx()` fixando os `d` em `dia` e `m` em `mes` e deixando `ufv` como parâmetro vaiável.
- então em `planilhas = list(map(f, ufv_name))` é obtida uma lista a partir dum [mapeamento](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) entre cada elemento de `ufv_name` e uma respectiva planilha.
- Então é só percorrer a lista e adicionar a cada planilha a arquivo `Relatorio_total.xlsx`.